# Google Admob Ads stopped showing recently

Tags: android, admob

I have an app in Maps and Navigation category which was running for more than an year on playstore. It contained Google's AdMob ads and from Sep 25, 18 my app suddenly stopped showing ads. No email notification was received from Google regarding any violation. My earning is less than $25 per week that's why I'm unable to contact AdMob support. What could be the possible reason for that?

Comment: your app id on adsmob may be expired please check adsmob console

Comment: There isn't any notification in admob console.

Comment: check you app in console..  there will be info or expiry date.

Comment: nothing is there.... no app id's expiry mentioned anywhere

Comment: @HamzaAhmedKhan did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Did anyone get a solution

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685?hl=en This help link can be helpful to contact admob team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ads just showed up after a month of ban from Google without any notification.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing on my YouTube channel, and it was because I hadn't accepted the latest terms. Are you sure you didn't accept the latest Admob terms when you were clicking around looking for the problem? That could have done it.